Bypass Emulator Detection
I want to use an app from my Android Emulator but on its welcome screen I got next error: Application error: a client-side exception has occured (see the browser console for more information). In the console: A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred and link to the next code:
function Z(e) {
    let {App: t, err: u} = e;
    return console.error(u),
    console.error("A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred"),
    i.loadPage("/_error").then(n=>{
        let {page: o, styleSheets: a} = n;
        return (null == s ? void 0 : s.Component) === o ? Promise.resolve().then(()=>m._(r(1053))).then(n=>Promise.resolve().then(()=>m._(r(26506))).then(r=>(t = r.default,
        e.App = t,
        n))).then(e=>({
            ErrorComponent: e.default,
            styleSheets: []
        })) : {
            ErrorComponent: o,
            styleSheets: a
        }
    }
    ).then(r=>{
        var i;
        let {ErrorComponent: l, styleSheets: s} = r
            , c = Q(t)
            , f = {
            Component: l,
            AppTree: c,
            router: n,
            ctx: {
                err: u,
                pathname: o.page,
                query: o.query,
                asPath: a,
                AppTree: c
            }
        };
        return Promise.resolve((null == (i = e.props) ? void 0 : i.err) ? e.props : (0,
        R.loadGetInitialProps)(t, f)).then(t=>es({
            ...e,
            err: u,
            Component: l,
            styleSheets: s,
            props: t
        }))
    }
    )
}

I don't encounter this error on my real device, so I suspect that problem with Emulator Detection.
I've tried to use AndRoPass to "hack" app's apk file but on signing the apk it throws the next error: <apk-filename>-aligned-debugSigned.apk is missing.
What's the options to bypass this emulator detection (or resolve issue if it's not an emulator detection)?
